# Adding Snow to footer with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

for Christmas I want to add snow to my website footer , something like this picture

`https://assets.stickpng.com/images/5847d74ccef1014c0b5e4806.png`

[image]

But I don't want to do it with image because it can't be responsive if I use image so I need a css code for that

I don't want to add snowflake , I'm already using this one:

`https://codepen.io/DesignCodeBuild/pen/GyNVbY`

I wan't to make website looks "It's a snow day and snow is sitting on the bottom of website"

Comment: Can I please ask why your image cannot be responsive in order to make a snow bed at the bottom? I get it that you would also like to have animated snowflakes. I'm stuck on the image rsponsiveness at the moment.

Comment: is that possible? I have no idea about front-end design and I almost forgot it , if that's possible can you tell me how should I do it?

Comment: This will be easier if I attempt an answer... Just one sec please....

Comment: Please add images as images, not code. Also see [ask]. You need to make an effort and show it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can have the image responsive on all screens by using CSS.

First in your HTML you can remove the image and just have an empty Div. The Class dictates where your CSS code will come from (snow-image).

```
<div class="snow-image">
  leave this empty as your image will soon appear here as a background.
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you could have something like this....

```
.snow-image{
background: url=(https://assets.stickpng.com.....);
bacgkround-size cover;
align-items: flex-end;
display: flex;
}
```

This will keep the image dimensions perfectly as a background of that Div rather than inserting the image dire3ctly to your HTML using `<img>`. It will also auto size to any screen width. Both of the flex commands (hopefully) make sure the snow bed image is positioned at the very bottom of it's parent Div. Hopefully then you can add that JS code you found at CodePen for the snowflakes and you're done :)

When you've done all this. If you cannot see the snow image it could mean the Div has no height. So you could add `height: --px;` to your CSS where `--` is exactly the same number of pixels tall as your image.

Comment: Hey @AlirezaBehnamnik . I had to alter my answer above so you may wish to go over it again.